# Can i use NserviceBus Retries without enabling DTC?

Tags: nservicebus

I have some technical issues working with DTC on our production env.
Is it possible to use the Retries feature without using the DTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable only DTC you need to add this to your endpoint config:

```
Configure.Transactions.Advanced(settings => settings.DisableDistributedTransactions());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This feature is not dependent on using DTC.

Comment: Sound reasonable, but -
When i configure the client with Configure.Transactions.Disable();
I don't see the reties in action.
Any idea why?

Comment: This may be dependent on the version you're using, but I think you need to use advanced configuration for transactions in order to get retries when your handler throws an exception.  Looks like this was actually a bug that was fixes very recently in v4:  https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/nservicebus/conversations/topics/17813